# Garden and Desert

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, anagram

> Deals with me rarely are regretted.
>
> I assure you, when last becomes first and the first last He'll be
>   Rejected.
>
> Adam Rejoiced in my newer locations --
>
> Dancing about again and again as I disappeared into Rojo
>   Conflagrations.

---

**What am I?**

---

Hint 1:

> You've never seen me before as I'm an *unpopular* **long, easy solution** that goes by no other name.

Hint 2:

> What's the opposite of **Rojo Conflagrations**?

Hint 3:

> What's the opposite of **Adam Rejoiced**?

Hint 4:

> What's the opposite of **Rejected**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I'm not confusing matters but is the answer a

> deceiver

Title: Garden and Desert

> These are opposites (as the hints stress) and the answers below use this.

Deals with me rarely are regretted.

> Deals with a deceiver are frequently regretted.

I assure you, when last becomes first and the first last He'll be Rejected.

> Switch first to last of deceiver to get received.

Adam Rejoiced in my newer locations

> Anagram deceiver to get Eve cried.

Dancing about again and again as I disappeared into Rojo Conflagrations.

> Anagram to get Verde Ice, Verde/Rojo are Span. Green/Red and Ice is  opposite of Fire (Conflagration/s).

I haven't solved the Steganography tag.

Comment: Tom -- I'm still green. I misused the steganography tag and will remove.  Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> The devil?

Because

> deals with the devil are commonly referenced,
>
>  "When the first becomes last" refers to the apocalypse, when something complicated happens, but the devil loses?
>
>  Not sure about this one, A reference to the story about the garden of Eden?
>
>  Dancing about in fire, sounds like him
>
>  The title refers to the Garden of Eden and the tempting of Jesus in the desert, both biblical stories involving the devil.

Comment: This is a useful answer, certainly on right track.  Try to focus on lines 2-4.